# php passing parms via the URL:

Tags: php

mimo.php is my main file... mainjob.php contains the div's that I want to `$get`

this is an example of my link...

.../pes/mimo.php?rack=1&jobs=0&hosts=1
this means that only entries related to rack 1 will be displayed.  The jobs list will not be displayed, but the host menu will be displayed

I'm passing the variables like this...

```
 echo $_GET["rack"] ;

 echo $_GET["jobs"] ;

 echo  $_GET["hosts"] ;
```

Rack would echo a grouping of divs with the contents: r1, r2, r3
Jobs it's grouping of divs: j1, j2, j3
Hosts: h1,h2, h3

I'm looking to connect the dots between passing the parameter and getting the data... Anyone feel me?

Best, William

Comment: what have you tries so far?

Comment: It's not `+` in the query string, it's `&` (as a separator). And do you mean retrieving data with `$_GET['rack']`?

Comment: yes, I am using $_get... I'm piecing it together a little at a time, won't go home till I figure it out... Thanks...

Comment: Use should use .../pes/mimo.php?rack=1&jobs=0&hosts=1 and then use $_GET['rack'] $_GET['jobs'] $_GET['hosts']

Comment: I just figured that out with       http://localhost/pes/mimi.phprack=1&jobs=0&hosts=1

<?php

echo $_GET["rack"] ;

echo $_GET["jobs"] ;

echo  $_GET["hosts"] ;

?>

this is where it gets hard...

rack1 to get my cluster divs
jobs to get job divs
hosts to get host divs

All on mainjob.php

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you mean by *get host divs*?

Comment: I just meant there are divs associated with each group... I got in trouble for being to wordy on this site, so was just trying to streamline it, as what the divs are actually called is not important. I'm looking for a method to this madness...  I won't knock anyone for not knowing this, as I respect everyone's time, especially someone trying to help me out... I'm sorry if I wasn't clear...

Comment: You should comment a little bit more your question... what have you tried and what are expecting to get? (**with code please**)

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect: 
.../pes/mimo.php?rack=1+jobs=0+hosts=1

Correct: .../pes/mimo.php?rack=1&jobs=0&hosts=1

```
echo $_GET["rack"]; // = 1
echo $_GET["jobs"]; // = 0
echo $_GET["hosts"]; // = 1
```

Using `+` is a space operator, meaning that rack = `1 jobs=0` (replace the + with an &)

For the browser, it uses the + for spaces, like `&jobs=my+job`, and then using  `$_GET["jobs"]` would return `my job`